# How to display the json data from mongo with arrays in ejs template?

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I'm using mongoose and express, among other things. I can display the top level values, like "number", but i can't get "contact.email". I've tried a lot of options in my server.js file, but I'm hoping someone can help me extract this info from the json on the ejs side. Thanks!

I'm using this code in my ejs template:

```
`<% for(var i= 0 ; i < myObj.length; i++) {%>
  <li>
    <span><%=myObj[i].number %>
  </li>
  <% } %>
   </ul>`
```

the schema

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e67c84a65a2893029991863"),
    "number" : 5,
    "contact" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e69a33a0208203268813e01"),
            "email" : "dhenley@gmail.com",

        }
    ]
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this below since you need another loop for accessing the contact array in your json:

```
<% for(var i= 0 ; i < myObj.length; i++) {%>
  <li>
    <span><%=myObj[i].number %>
  </li>
   <ul>
   for(var j=0 ; j < myObj[i].contact.length; j++)
   <li>
    <span><%=myObj[i].contact[j].email %>
  </li>
   <% } %>
  </ul>
  <% } %>
   </ul>`
```

Comment: This was a long the lines of what I figured I might need, but now I'm getting a error. Its awaiting a catch or an async or catch on my server.js file. Does that sound right?

Comment: You could use a catch

Comment: I tracked down the catch error to the ejs code, still working on fixing that.

Comment: The opening curly bracket was missing from the second for loop in your example, sadly it took me a long time to notice this. I will edit it for you, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By Assuming that your object format is as below:-

```
 var myObj= {
   "_id" : ObjectId("5e67c84a65a2893029991863"),
   "number" : 5,
   "contact" : [{
     "_id": ObjectId("5e69a33a0208203268813e01"),
       "email": "dhenley@gmail.com"
   }]
 };
```

You have to loop your data like as below:-

```
<span><%=myObj.number %></span>
<ul>
  <% for(var i= 0 ; i < myObj.contact.length; i++) {%>
  <li><%=myObj.contact[i].email %></li>
  <% } %>
</ul>`
```

Note:- As `myObj` is an object. and `myObj.contact` is an `array` of `myObj`. so in this case you have to loop your `myObj.contact`.

Comment: I've tried this way before and it doesn't like myObj.contact.length   it says length undefined. From what I read you can't do the dot notation here.

Comment: @BrandoThom Please add your JSON format. so i  can help you better.